# How to append a tuple to a numpy array without it being preformed element-wise?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I try

`x = np.append(x, (2,3))`

the tuple `(2,3)` does not get appended to the end of the array, rather `2` and `3` get appended individually, even if I originally declared `x` as

`x = np.array([], dtype = tuple)`

or

`x = np.array([], dtype = (int,2))`

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Why are you `append`ing to NumPy arrays? That's almost never a good idea.

Comment: @user2357112 Because I am in a situation where it is not possible to know ahead of time how many elements are going to be in the array. Also I was under the impression that appending in `numpy` is faster than in python

Comment: `append`ing to NumPy arrays is **catastrophically** slower than `append`ing to ordinary lists. It's an operation that they are not at all designed for.

Comment: There's not such `dtype=tuple`; that is understood to be `dtype=object`.  But the proper way depends on what result you want.  What kind of a array do you want?  2d of ints, structured, object, or a random choice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with @user2357112 comment:

> appending to NumPy arrays is catastrophically slower than appending to ordinary lists. It's an operation that they are not at all designed for

Here's a little benchmark:

```
# measure execution time
import timeit
import numpy as np


def f1(num_iterations):
    x = np.dtype((np.int32, (2, 1)))

    for i in range(num_iterations):
        x = np.append(x, (i, i))


def f2(num_iterations):
    x = np.array([(0, 0)])

    for i in range(num_iterations):
        x = np.vstack((x, (i, i)))


def f3(num_iterations):
    x = []
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        x.append((i, i))

    x = np.array(x)

N = 50000

print timeit.timeit('f1(N)', setup='from __main__ import f1, N', number=1)
print timeit.timeit('f2(N)', setup='from __main__ import f2, N', number=1)
print timeit.timeit('f3(N)', setup='from __main__ import f3, N', number=1)
```

I wouldn't use neither np.append nor vstack, I'd just create my python array properly and then use it to construct the np.array

**EDIT**

Here's the benchmark output on my laptop:

- append: 12.4983000173
- vstack: 1.60663705793
- list:   0.0252208517006

[Finished in 14.3s]

Comment: @OhadEytan I've edited my answer for N=50000, laptop with i-7 2.6Ghz over here

Comment: I ended up just using a python list

Comment: Don't trust these timings - the functions don't produce the same result. Yes, list append is faster, but it doesn't say anything meaningful about `np.append` compared to `np.vstack`.  See my answer for corrected timings.

Answer (score 3):

You need to supply the shape to numpy dtype, like so:

```
x = np.dtype((np.int32, (1,2))) 
x = np.append(x,(2,3))
```

Outputs

```
array([dtype(('<i4', (2, 3))), 1, 2], dtype=object)
```

[Reference][1]http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Comment: You produced an array that contains a `dtype` as object.  What's the value of that?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you mean, you can use `vstack`:

```
>>> a = np.array([(1,2),(3,4)])
>>> a = np.vstack((a, (4,5)))
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5]])
```

Comment: That sounds like the exact opposite of what the questioner is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`np.append` is easy to use with a case like:

```
In [94]: np.append([1,2,3],4)
Out[94]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

but its first example is harder to understand.  It shows the same sort of flat concatenate that bothers you:

```
>>> np.append([1, 2, 3], [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Stripped of dimensional tests, `np.append` does

```
In [166]: np.append(np.array([1,2],int),(2,3))
Out[166]: array([1, 2, 2, 3])

In [167]: np.concatenate([np.array([1,2],int),np.array((2,3))])
Out[167]: array([1, 2, 2, 3])
```

So except for the simplest cases you need to understand what `np.array((2,3))` does, and how `concatenate` handles dimensions.

So apart from the speed issues, `np.append` can be trickier to use that the interface suggests.  The parallels to list `append` are only superficial.

As for `append` (or `concatenate`) with `dtype=object` (not `dtype=tuple`) or a compound `dtype` ('i,i'), I couldn't tell you what happens without testing.  At a minimum the inputs should already be arrays, and should have a matching `dtype`.  Otherwise the results can unpredicatable.

## edit

Don't trust the timings in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38985245/901925.  The functions don't produce the same things.

Corrected functions:

```
In [233]: def g1(num_iterations):
     ...:     x = np.ones((0,2),int)
     ...:     for i in range(num_iterations):
     ...:         x = np.append(x, [(i, i)], axis=0)
     ...:     return x
     ...: 
     ...: def g2(num_iterations):
     ...:     x = np.ones((0, 2),int)
     ...:     for i in range(num_iterations):
     ...:         x = np.vstack((x, (i, i)))
     ...:     return x
     ...: 
     ...: def g3(num_iterations):
     ...:     x = []
     ...:     for i in range(num_iterations):
     ...:         x.append((i, i))
     ...:     x = np.array(x)
     ...:     return x
     ...: 
In [234]: g1(3)
Out[234]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
In [235]: g2(3)
Out[235]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
In [236]: g3(3)
Out[236]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

`np.append` and `np.vstack` timings are much closer.  Both use `np.concatenate` to do the actual joining.  They differ in how the inputs are processed prior to sending them to `concatenate`.

```
In [237]: timeit g1(1000)
9.69 ms ± 6.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [238]: timeit g2(1000)
12.8 ms ± 7.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [239]: timeit g3(1000)
537 µs ± 2.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

The wrong results.  Note that `f1` produces a 1d object dtype array, because the starting value is object dtype array, and there's not `axis` parameter.  `f2` duplicates the starting array.

```
In [240]: f1(3)
Out[240]: array([dtype(('<i4', (2, 1))), 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], dtype=object)
In [241]: f2(3)
Out[241]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

Not only is it slower to use `np.append` or `np.vstack` in a loop, it is also hard to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any special insight as to why this works, but:

```
x = np.array([1, 3, 2, (5,7), 4])
mytuple = [(2, 3)]
mytuplearray = np.empty(len(mytuple), dtype=object)
mytuplearray[:] = mytuple
y = np.append(x, mytuplearray)
print(y)                                      #   [1 3 2 (5, 7) 4 (2, 3)]
```

As others have correctly pointed out, this is a slow operation with numpy arrays. If you're just building some code from scratch, try to use some other data type. But if you know your array will always remain small or you're not going to append much or if you have existing code that you need to tweak quickly, then go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

simplest way:

```
x=np.append(x,None)
x[-1]=(2,3)
```