# Inserting tuple into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

Is there any way to insert a tuple into numpy array? Let's say I have:

> [1,2,3,4,5,6]

But what I want is:

> [1,2,3,(4,5,6)]

Comment: You can't.  Your example suggests you are working with lists, not arrays.  Don't confuse us, or yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `append()`

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.append((4,5,6))
```

Some [documentations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) you may find useful

Comment: I've already tried it, but it still gives me [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: @siwakw7 it sounds really strange to me. What IDE and Python version are you using?

Comment: @siwakw7 You are sure you are using `append`, not `extend`? Perhaps you could show us the code you actually ran.

Comment: Note that he said he is using a numpy array, not a list. As far as I know, a numpy array does not even have any append method. Maybe it could help to understand the purpose of the question, then one might solve that. As it is now it is hard to imagine any advantage by constructing such an object.

Comment: I'm making an array with `arr=np.array([])` end then, just for example, trying to put a tuple into it by `arr = np.append(arr,(4,5,6))` (also tried non numpy method)

Comment: @siwakw7 try `a = np.vstack((a,(4,5,6)))`. Append should work anyway but it is super slow. Check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985011/how-to-append-a-tuple-to-a-numpy-array-without-it-being-preformed-element-wise) here

Comment: @NicoCaldo, `np.append` isn't slower than `np.vstack`.  The link is comparing it to list append.

Comment: @hpaulj it is. It compares `append` on `np` array, `vstack` on `np` array and `append` on list. Read carefully

Comment: Read your comment carefully or the linked answer?  The linked answer compares `np.append`, `np.vstack` and `append`.  While list append is clearly fastest, the relative speeds of `np.append` and `np.vstack` are questionable.  Those timed functions don't produce the same result.  In any case, for @siwakw7 case, the best `vstack` can do is `array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])`.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah python list is the best option

Answer (score 0):

Nico is right - list append can create the object you **show**:

```
In [155]: alist = [1,2,3]
In [156]: alist.append((4,5,6))
In [157]: alist
Out[157]: [1, 2, 3, (4, 5, 6)]
```

You misread Nico, and tried `np.append`.  It is not a list append clone!

First look at this array:

```
In [165]: arr = np.array([1,2,3])
In [166]: arr
Out[166]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [167]: print(arr)
[1 2 3]
```

It doesn't display as a list.  It is not a list, and cannot hold a tuple.  It can only hold integers (check the `dtype`).

`np.append` clearly says that it flattens all inputs:

```
In [168]: arr1 = np.append(arr,(4,5,6))
In [169]: arr1
Out[169]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

A clearer way to express this

```
In [170]: np.hstack((arr, np.array([4,5,6])))
Out[170]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

As for speed - list append is the best way to go if you are building lists in  a loop.  Copying list methods with arrays is a bad idea.